# Don't understand why I am getting list index out of range here

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote this to simulate studying for a test

```
#number of questions
    qList = [] * q
    #question numbers
    for i in range(len(qList)):
        qList[i] = i + 1
    #questions studied
    sList = [] * s
    for i in range (0,s):
        x = randint(0,len(qList))
        sList[i] = qList[x]

    #questions passed
    pList = []
    for i in range(len(sList)):
        if i in sList and i in qList:
            pList.apppend(i)
```

the line `sList[i] = qList[x]` gives me an index out of range error. I haven't used lists in a while and I can't figure out what is wrong here.

I am trying to get the output here as three lists

- a list of questions
- the questions that have been studied
- the questions passed

Answer (score 0):

[`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) includes both boundaries:

> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Change invocation to:

```py
x = randint(0, len(qList) - 1)
# or
x = randrange(0, len(qList))
```

Also you are instantiating empty arrays, you need to pass some element so it can be repeated (or better use [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)):

```py
qList = [1] * q
sList = [1] * s
```

Comment: Now that i have fixed that, my code is saying theat list has no atribut append

Comment: @RayFavaza was not able to repro with the OP code.